# How can I get the texture color data from GLEED2D's level file?

Tags: xna, c#, textures, color

I've hit a little snag in my game. It's a 2D platform game and I need to check for collisions against the level. I'm using [GLEED2D](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D) to create the map.

I'd like to do per-pixel collision checking, but I don't know how to get the texture color values out of the Level.cs file provided by GLEED2D.

If any one can point me in the right direction that be great -- or if they're are any better level mapping programs with similar features as GLEED2D that would be better to use for this type of game, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: FYI, Gleed2D is now hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 - Making the Textures accessible from Level.cs**

The texture for each item is being stored inside the `TextureItem` class inside `Level.cs`. You should be able find something like this on your file:

```
public partial class TextureItem : Item
{
    Texture2D texture;

    public override void load(ContentManager cm)
    {
        // Your load implementation
    }
}
```

Now, start by making it public:

```
public partial class TextureItem : Item
{
    public Texture2D Texture;

    public override void load(ContentManager cm)
    {
        // Your load implementation
    }
}
```

And then it's simply a matter of acessing the texture directly. Example:

```
Level level = Level.FromFile("map.xml", Content);

foreach(Layer layer in level.Layers)
{
    foreach(Item item in layer.Items)
    {
        ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem;
        if(imageItem != null)
        {
            Texture2D texture = imageItem.Texture;
            // Do something with texture, such as per pixel collision detection
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - Handling per-pixel collision detection in XNA**

In case you're not familiar with this process, here's two good references on the topic:

1. [Collision Series 2: 2D Per-Pixel Collision](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel) to learn how to implement the basics in XNA. The core feature needed is pretty much the [Texture.GetData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.getdata.aspx) method which allows you to get back pixel color information from any texture.
2. [Sonic Physics Guide](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_Physics_Guide) which describes physics in Sonic games. They also used per-pixel collision detection with the terrain so you might be able to get some tips out of it.

Comment: it is already set to public under TextureItem : Item.
any other ideas ?

Comment: It's not set to public on the copy that you download from the GLEED2D website (I checked), but... so? If it's already set to public, just use it. I demonstrated how in my answer...

Comment: the problem that's occurring is that I already set it to public, when I want to use it, I get 'GLEED2D.Item' does not contain a definition for 'texture' and no extension method 'texture' accepting a first argument of type 'GLEED2D.Item' could be found

Comment: And the compiler is right because there is really no `texture` member on the `Item` class. It only exists on the **`ImageItem`** class. So you need to *downcast* your object to `ImageItem`, just like I showed you in my example: `ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem; if(imageItem != null) { Do something with imageItem.texture }`

Comment: No problem. By the way, I think it's really worth dedicating some time to building and solidifying your general programming and object oriented skills, before diving into game programming. Makes things a lot easier later.